# DynamoDB modelling question: table with games between player1 and player2, how to get all games involving a given player

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Am storing games in a database. Games are between two players: call them player1 and player2. I have a document per game, with keys 'player1' and 'player2' containing the player ids. Obviously a given player could appear in either the player1 or player2 key depending on the draw.

Is there a way to structure my data so that I can efficiently find all games for a given player? I know that a query where player1=playerId OR player2=playerId is not possible in dynamo. Am looking for ideas on how to manage it. I started by creating "linked" documents with playerId as the partition key and date/time of game as the sort key. But this is getting messy!

Maybe my best option is to create two GSIs (on player1 and player2) and do an application level union.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to model a one to many relationship between players and games?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan, thanks for response, but not really a one to many problem here, or at least I don't think so. In a one-to-many normally you'd have a foreign key on the game table using the player id. In my case I do have that FK - but it can appear in either game.player1 or game.player2. In SQL days there would be a couple of ways to model this: either directly with player1 and player2 FKs on game table, or indirectly using a join table player_game with compound PK of {gameId, playerId, role} where role is "player1" or "player2"

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your question.  You asked "Is there a way to structure my data so that I can efficiently find all games for a given player?"  The relationship from Player to Games sounds like a one-to-many, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, your access patterns are

1. Fetch games for a player
2. Fetch most recent game for a player (based on comments on an earlier post)

Let's start by modeling the relationship between two players playing a game.  I'll call it a Match (naming is hard).  You could store the Matches between players like this:

[image: Matches between players]

I've made up a few attributes on the Match item to illustrate the concept. I'm using a simple primary key with the format MATCH#[KSUID].  If you're not familiar, a [KSUID](https://segment.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-the-uuid/) is a unique identifier that is  sortable *and* has a built-in time component.  You can use them like UUIDs, but get the useful side effect of sortability based on time.  This feature of KSUIDs will be useful when retrieving the latest Match.

We can create two secondary indexes to model the matches from either players perspective.  For example, I'll create a secondary index named Player1Index and give it a GSIPK of the `player1` attribute, and the GSISK could be the `PK` of your main table.  Using the example above, your data would look like this

[image: Player1Index]

Similarly, the Player2Index would look like this

[image: Player2Index]

Notice that the KSUID is part of the sort key in both indexes, which means fetching matches by a player will automatically sort the matches in the order they were created.  This would allow for your second access pattern where you fetch the latest match for a given player.

EDIT:  If the goal is to get *all* matches where a given player was player1 *or* player2, you could create a Match item collection that contains each player as a separate item within the collection.  For example:

[image]

Then you could create an inverted secondary index, swapping the PK/SK patterns in the index.  That would look like this:

[image]

In this model, the secondary index would contain *all* matches for a given player, regardless of their role in the match.  You may prefer this solution since you could grab the data in a single query with a single index.  Pagination would be easier than the first approach.

Whichever path you take, the goal is to pre-join the data you need so it can be fetched in a single query.  Sure, you could use the former pattern and query two indexes, and merge results in your application.  Making two queries (versus one) isn't the worst thing in the world, but is way less satisfying than fetching the data all at once!

Comment: Thanks, this is very very close to what I came up with using two GSIs. Was not aware of KSUID - that could be super useful. We do need to query both secondary indexes to get all matches for a player though right? In your example, Bob appears as player1 and player2. This has implications for paging, although not a big issue for my use case - I'm setting a limit of 100 on each GSI query and then limiting the returned union to 100.

Comment: I added another example that breaks up Matches into item collections.  It's not perfect but would let you fetch all matches for a player regardless of their role as player1 or player2.

Comment: Thanks Seth, I think you've covered all the bases. Of course with your item collection approach, if there is additional data for a match we either have to duplicate it or store in a separate table. Obvious example is the score, which is useful to have in query results but is also changeable... so has to be duplicated. I am going with the dual GSI and union of queries for now!!